# How to get the total number of lines in an output

Tags: python

I made this code that basically calculates all the different combinations to make a dollar using pennies, nickels, quarters and dollar coins. The code works fine, but I need it to also tell me the total number of possibilities it printed, at the end of the code. I would appreciate some help :)

```
def alter(s, coins_free, coins_in_use):
  if sum(coins_in_use) == s:
    yield coins_in_use
  elif sum(coins_in_use) > s:
    pass
  elif coins_free == []:
    pass
  else:
    for c in alter(n, coins_free[:], coins_in_use+[coins_free[0]]):
      yield c
    for c in alter(n, coins_free [1:], coins_in_use):
        yield c
n = 100
coins = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100]

solution = [s for s in alter(n, coins, [])]
for s in solution:
  print(s)
```

Comment: `len(soloution)`? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `len(solution)` at the end of your code like the following.

```
solution = [s for s in alter(n, coins, [])]
for s in solution:
  print(s)

print(f'Total no of possibilities: {len(solution)}')
```

**Output:**

```
Total no of possibilities: 243
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not actually need to make a list. In that case, you could use [`enumerate(start=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
possibilities = alter(n, coins, [])
i = 0  # Just in case there are no possibilities
for i, p in enumerate(possibilities, 1):
    print(p)
print('Total number of possibilities:', i)
```

Or of course, you could do it manually:

```
i = 0
for p in possibilities:
    print(p)
    i += 1
print('Total number of possibilities:', i)
```

---

Although, FWIW, if you do need to make a list, the comprehension is kind of redundant and this is cleaner:

```
solution = list(alter(n, coins, []))
```